# Clojure: gen-class and import it in java; packages, paths, classpaths

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, java-interop

I want to call Clojure code compiled to a class from Java.

Clojure class:

```
(ns clj.core)

(gen-class
 :name de.wt.TestClj
 :state state
 :init init
 :prefix "-"
 :main false
 :methods [[setValue [String] void]
           [getValue [] String]])

(defn -init []
  [[] (atom {:value ""})])

(defn -setValue [this val]
  (swap! (.state this) assoc :value val))

(defn -getValue [this]
  (@(.state this) :value))
```

Compiled with `lein uberjar` and copied the output -standalone.jar into the Java project under subdirs `de/wt`.

The .java file:

```
import de.wt.TestClj;

class CljTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestClj test = new TestClj();
        System.out.println("Pre: " + test.getValue());
        test.setValue("foo");
        System.out.println("Post: " + test.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now when I try to compile

```
~/testbed/cljava/java % tree                                                                 [1 14:44:53]
.
├── CljTest.java
├── de
│   └── wt
│       └── TestClj.jar
└── TestClj.jar

2 directories, 3 files
~/testbed/cljava/java % javac -cp ./:./de/wt/TestClj.jar CljTest.java                        

CljTest.java:1: error: package de.wt does not exist
import de.wt.TestClj;
^
CljTest.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
TestClj test = new TestClj();
^
symbol:   class TestClj
location: class CljTest
CljTest.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
TestClj test = new TestClj();
^
symbol:   class TestClj
location: class CljTest
3 errors
```

What scheme do I need to follow when naming files/packages, creating directories and setting class paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see the java class in your jar, something like:

```
 $ jar tvf target/default-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar | grep TestClj
 2090 Mon Jan 01 18:43:12 CET 2018 de/wt/TestClj.class
```

If not, make sure you have an `:aot` (ahead-of-time compilation) directive in your project.clj:

```
(defproject default "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :aot [clj.core]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]])
```

Once you see the `.class` file in your jar, with the jar in your classpath the import you have in your Java code should work fine.

As noted in the docs (https://clojure.org/reference/compilation):

> Clojure compiles all code you load on-the-fly into JVM bytecode, but sometimes it is advantageous to compile ahead-of-time (AOT). Some reasons to use AOT compilation are:
>
> To deliver your application without source
>
> To speed up application startup
>
> **To generate named classes for use by Java**
>
> To create an application that does not need runtime bytecode generation and custom classloaders

Also see http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/interop.html:

> AOT
>
> `gen-class` requires ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation. It means that before using the classes defined with `gen-class`, the Clojure compiler needs to produce .class files from `gen-class` definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already added `:aot`, but obviously it didn't rebuild cleanly for some reason. Your trick with the `jar` command is a good one!

Comment: Now I can compile with `javac -cp ./TestClj.jar CljTest.java` and run with `java -cp .:./TestClj.jar CljTest`. Awesomely easy!